# DevExpress gridview weird behavior?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I have the following lines of code that bind the gridview:

```
DataView DataV = new DataView(CommonClasses.CommonMethods.ConvertTo(ProductManager.Initialize().GetProductUploadDocument("ProductUploadDocument.ProductID =@ProductID", "DECLARE @ProductID numeric(18,0) set @ProductID=" + ProductID)));

ASPxGridViewProductDocuments.DataSource = DataV;
ASPxGridViewProductDocuments.DataBind();
```

An issue have arrised lately, the girdview will view several records, contain an a button that will open an image, what happense is that when a user click on the frist image it opened, he then closes the window then open the second image, after that when tries to open the first image, the second image is opened and the more the reocrds in the grid the more frustrating this will get.

This grid was working fine for years, but recently they have put the application in a different server, and i want to note that they are using a balancer becuase there are many users working on the application.

I have tested this issue and tried to do everything to produce this problem in my development machine but i couldn't.

Now the question is, is that my problem to fix as the developer, or it's an enviorment issue ?

Comment: It would be better to provide a sample project for solving the problem.

Comment: There is no sample project, this only occures in production envoirment and i want to know why and how.

Comment: Since the issue cannot be reproduced even on your dev machine, without a sample project with the code, it would be even harder to figure out the reason of this issue.

Comment: So isn't there anything that i can do ?

Comment: I didn't say so. What I said is it's hard to make an helpful answer for you. If I could, I would do that; but I'm unable to, so I suggested that to provide a sample project, since I'm afraid that it would be also hard for people to answer with the known information we can see here.